# How to match newline in RegEx without using a modifier?

Tags: php, regex

For example, if I wanted to match text with multiple lines I could use the `/s` modifier in preg_match.

Or I could use a character class like `[^!]+` instead of the `.+`. (assuming I didn't have any exclamation points in my RegEx)

Problem is there might be an exclamation mark sometimes. Also, when I do this it is greedy and matches all the way to the end.

Sorry for the newbie question but I can't test `/s` in http://regexpal.com/ and I really like its interface. Basically I want a character class that won't be used in the text and one that isn't greedy so it doesn't try to go as far as it can.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want the engine not to **try to go as far as it can**, you may make it lazy by appending `?` to `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using

```
(.|\n)
```

That should explicitely allow newlines, too.